# A basic MATLab question regarding iterations

Tags: matlab

Suppose I want to run a loop for integers $i = 2,2^2,2^3, \dots,2^n$

How would I do this? That is, suppose I want to evaluate some function f(i) through the increments $2, 2^2, 2^3$. I understand that for loops in MatLab can only take arithmetic difference step size, but not geometric ones.

Comment: Why Matlab and not Octave? Why not set p = 2^i and continue with calculations within the loop?

Comment: I agree. I personally prefer Octave to Matlab but that is just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the loop from $i=1\dots n$ and calculate the power of $2$ manually

Psuedocode:

```
k = 2
for 0:1:n-1
  k = k*2 
  do something
end
```

Comment: And what if $f(i)$ is a more complicated function? I am trying to apply the idea to more general functions

Comment: "Do something" means compute $f(k)$

Comment: Ok, but what if I don't want to display $i$? I am a beginner at this sorry.

Comment: You can avoid displaying the indermediate data with " ; " (here k = k*2; instead of k = k*2)

Comment: Oh okay, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in *octave* (Matlab is similar)

```
for k=1:n
    i=2^k;
     blah blah blah
end
```

If you really want to show off your Octave/Matlab skills, you can do this

```
for k=2.^(1:10), disp(k);end
```

Replace disp with your code

*Note:* For statement in Octave and Matlab takes a row vector. The syntax is

```
for variable=columns
    body
end
```

The variable iterates over the columns. The most common usage for columns is *a:b*

Comment: More stupid question, but you did .^ because (1:10) is an array right?

Comment: Yes. As I wrote in my latest edit. you can put anything after = for example: *for x=[1,7,3,10], disp(x); end*